# Git: How do I pull to a server without bringing the metadata?

Tags: wordpress, git, git-submodules

I have a staging server I'd like to set up to git pull whenever updates are made to a BitBucket repo. It would be a single repo with multiple submodules, but I can break it apart if that's better.

It'd be a theme that goes to wp-content/themes/

And single/multiple plugins that go to wpp-content/plugins

My question is, (1) is this good practice? and (2) how can I pull the changes without introducing the .git metadata to those (or any public) directory? I assume the metadata has to be somewhere, but how can I hide it?

If this is too vague, please feel free to ask for clarification on something.

Thanks!

Comment: For WordPress, I found deploying using [Capistrano](http://www.capistranorb.com) to control git worked well. [This article](http://www.chefduweb.nl/2013/09/deploying-wordpress-part-2-capistrano/) seems to be roughly the setup I use; you can see the copy stage excludes the metadata when deploying. So basically, you check in your local changes, and `cap deploy` grabs them out to a repo on the remote server, then copies them across to your staging/production area without the metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the whole thing under git ?

Use .htaccess to disallow the .git folder.

You can use multiple repositories but updating means going to each one and git pull / git fetch git merge.

you could also move the .git directory outside of the web root, make a file called .git with the contents

```
`gitdir: /path/to/.git`
```